# Duplicate events in a single frame in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

I'm testing a sub-optimal but really simple CSS animation in Chrome on Mac. In the dev tools, I see that "recalculate style" and subsequent activities are being executed multiple times in a single frame. "Update layer tree" is being called 3 times.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome timeline event log]

I do not see this behavior in Chrome on Windows. I also do not see equivalent behavior in Firefox.

Here is the simple demo I'm using: http://s.codepen.io/lonekorean/debug/44cf0a50e321de7ec7ff4fac5d3f4514

Why am I seeing these events repeated? It seems very inefficient for Chrome to redo that work in the same frame, so I would like to understand why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar was asked previously on Google Forums, so I've quoted the explanation given below:

> The signal that we use for frame boundaries is emitted when the
> compositor actually draws layers, and there are plenty of
> opportunities for the compositor to bail out before actually drawing,
> most common being the update being outside of view-port. So the flow
> in your case is likely as this:
>
> - you invalidate styles;
> - the main thread requests a frame from the impl side;
> - the impl side begins a frame and requests a main thread frame;
> - the main thread performs style recalc/layout/update layer tree;
> - it turns out there are no invalidations within the visible area;
> - frame is not drawn. (the above is repeated several times, then something is actually drawn, and at this point we mark next frame
>   boundary in Timeline).
>
> **Comment by:** Andrey Kosyakov

**Source:** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/JaWHxD6oaXU

From what I understand, invalidating styles is the process of deciding which elements need to have their computed styles recalculated. This is done by storing meta data of the relationships between the elements in the form of [Descendant Invalidation Sets](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vEW86DaeVs4uQzNFI5R-_xS9TcS1Cs_EUsHRSgCHGu8/edit#heading=h.xa3ovcncd2vp).

### Update:

I can replicate the same behaviour in on Chrome for Windows as you can see below:

[image: Windows]

I can't see any reason why the compositor would bail out but I'm not so familiar with the intricate details of this. It's somewhat complicated.

[image: Paint Profiler]

Comment: Hm, nothing I am animating appears outside of the viewport. But from the doc you linked maybe parts of the tree are being invalidated even when they don't need to be? Still confused why this doesn't happen on Windows.

Comment: @lonekorean I was able to replicate this in Chrome for Windows. See my update above.

Comment: Thanks Gideon, it actually makes me feel better that this can happen in Windows too. :) Seems like there can be many factors (memory, CPU, GPU, etc.) that could affect the exact rendering behavior of Chrome. I think the fact that there is a continuous animation causes Chrome to recalc multiple times a frame? It's still only painting once per frame, which I would expect.